# How should I align items inside of a card?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I'm using angular, html and css to build my first side project and have started using flex to align items on my page. The main portion of my app is simply cards displaying info for upcoming concerts in the metro area.

Flex seems to be working for aligning the cards themselves, however I am having trouble getting consistent alignments for items *inside* each card. When I add styling of "padding-top: 30%" or "justify-content: flex-end" for items inside of the cards, it shows different alignments on different cards, as each card has different info with different lengths of text, causing alignments to be different per card (screenshot below).

I'm using *ngFor to loop through all of the upcoming shows and want to apply the same styling to all cards to get a consistent look for everything.

Sorry I know it's a little messy with combination of css classes and inline styling, I'm just trying to get everything to look how I want it to before I clean it up entirely.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[Screenshot of cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YznO0.jpg)

```
    <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor='let show of showsToDisplay'>
        <h6>{{ show.venue.displayName }}</h6>
        <div class="card card:hover border-secondary mb-8 rounded" style="width: 18rem; height: 36rem; padding-bottom: 25%;">
          <img id="cardImage" [src]="show.uri">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>{{ show.performance[0].artist.displayName }}</h3>
            <h5 class="text-secondary" *ngIf="show.performance[1]">{{ show.performance[1].artist.displayName }}</h5>
            <h6 class="text-secondary" *ngIf="show.performance[2]">{{ show.performance[2].artist.displayName }}</h6>
            <br>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ show.start.date }}
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <div style="justify-content: flex-end;">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Tickets</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: You could set the `height` property of each card component if you want each card element to be aligned regardless of if another element is missing or not. Doing this means you'll drop the `*ngIf ` and display nothing instead (e.g: `<h5 class="text-secondary">{{ show.performance[1]?.artist.displayName }}</h5>
`). Keep in mind what you want to do if the text ends up overflowing from the height you set (maybe use ellipsis?)

Comment: The inner content alignment her not related to flexbox. On card one you got  3 elements VS card-three 1 element (This is not a table). Use min-height and first try to solve this idea on photoshop or sketch (Decide about the layout of un-even content cards)